# Script para contar números

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo que hacer un script con un procedimiento que me cuente los números desde 1 hasta un número introducido por el usuario. De momento tengo esto:

```
create or replace procedure rang (minimo number, maximo number)
is
begin
  minimo:=1;
  WHILE minimo <= maximo LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HOLA');
  minimo:=i+1;
  END LOOP;
end rang;
```

No sé cómo hacerlo, cómo debo poner las variables para que una sea por defecto y la otra se la tenga que preguntar al usuario ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RANG(MAXIMO IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1..MAXIMO
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I);  
    END LOOP;

END;



BEGIN 
    RANG(10);
END;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]